# How do I add watermark/background image in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

How can I add a watermark or a background image in Google Docs?

Comment: This is no longer supported because you can't use CSS.

Comment: @batpigandme Do you know of an official source that describes that? I agree that the lack of CSS is the reason, but I've only found forums that mention it, and for the sake of an "authoritative" answer, I figure a reference by Google is ideal.

Comment: @john bensin That's what I was going by as well/why I didn't make this an official answer, but I'll poke around

Comment: Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible. Google Drive has no such feature.